# What is the best way to auto failover to backup WAN link for web server

Tags: failover, isp

Iam looking for the best way to ensure my server ( application ) remains available for all my users (on web/LAN/WAN ), when my primary ISP link fails.

My server is behind a firewall on which both my primary & secondary links land.

1. I have already assigned multiple IPs (both ISP's static IP) to the 'A' record ( host.example.com ) in the DNS.  However in a round robin scenario is there a way I can ensure that my web user will not see a "cannot dislay web page" error ever ??
2. What are the better methods to achieve this??

Comment: Please give us more informations about your setup : what kind of link, hardware and software used on firewall & server.

Answer (score 1):

- Get an link that doesn't fail (rack/colocation/dedicated/vps/"cloud", they have several ISP links)
- Get both ISPs to route to the IP addresses you have, configure it as a bridge and add the IP addresses there.